# Getting serial port list

Tags: c#, thread-safety, iterator, reactive-programming

Needed to get a local serial port list. `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()` returns names but not the descriptions like you can see in Device Manager: `COM6` vs. `USB Serial Port (COM6)`…

There is also no way to subscribe to plug-and-play port list changes.

Here comes the solution. Repository at [GitHub](https://github.com/dmitrynogin/PnP).

To consume the lib:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var ports = new ComPortList())
    {
        WriteLine(Join("\n", ports));
        ports.Subscribe(WriteLine);                
        ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Sample output on my machine is:

```
USB Serial Port (COM6)
USB Serial Port (COM6) was removed.
USB Serial Port (COM6) was added.
```

Where library code is:

```
public class ComPortList : 
    Enumerable<ComPort>, IObservable<ComPortUpdate>, IDisposable
{
    public ComPortList()
    {
        Watcher = new PnPWatcher();
        Items = new List<ComPort>();
        Subject = new Subject<ComPortUpdate>();
        Watcher.Change += (s, e) => Sync();
        Sync();
    }

    PnPWatcher Watcher { get; }
    List<ComPort> Items { get; }
    Subject<ComPortUpdate> Subject { get; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Watcher.Dispose();
        Subject.Dispose();
    }

    public override IEnumerator<ComPort> GetEnumerator()
    {
        lock (Items)
            return Items.ToList().GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<ComPortUpdate> observer) =>
        Subject.Subscribe(observer);

    void Sync()
    {
        lock (Items)
        {
            var items = ComPort.Detect();

            foreach (var port in Items.Except(items).ToArray())
            {                    
                Items.Remove(port);
                Subject.OnNext(new ComPortRemoval(port));
            }

            foreach (var port in items.Except(Items).ToArray())
            {
                Items.Add(port);
                Subject.OnNext(new ComPortAddition(port));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using:

```
public class ComPort : ValueObject<ComPort>
{
    public static ComPort[] Detect()
    {
        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher
            ("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE ClassGuid='{4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}'"))
        {
            return searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementBaseObject>()
                .Select(p => new ComPort($"{p["Caption"]}"))
                .ToArray();
        }
    }

    ComPort(string description)
    {
        Description = description;
        Name = new string(
            description
                .Reverse()
                .SkipWhile(c => c != ')')
                .TakeWhile(c => c != '(')
                .Reverse()
                .ToArray())
            .TrimStart('(')
            .TrimEnd(')');
    }

    public string Description { get; }
    public string Name { get; }

    public override string ToString() => Description;
    protected override IEnumerable<object> EqualityCheckAttributes =>
        new object[] { Name, Description };
}
```

And:

```
class PnPWatcher : IDisposable
{
    const string Query =
        "SELECT * FROM Win32_DeviceChangeEvent";

    public PnPWatcher()
    {
        Watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(Query);
        Watcher.EventArrived += (s, e) => Change(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        Watcher.Start();
    }

    ManagementEventWatcher Watcher { get; }
    SynchronizationContext Context { get; }

    public void Dispose() => Watcher.Dispose();
    public event EventHandler Change = delegate { };
}
```

Event classes are:

```
public abstract class ComPortUpdate
{
    public ComPortUpdate(ComPort port) => Port = port;
    public ComPort Port { get; }
}

public class ComPortAddition : ComPortUpdate
{
    public ComPortAddition(ComPort port) : base(port) { }
    public override string ToString() => $"{Port} was added.";
}

public class ComPortRemoval : ComPortUpdate
{
    public ComPortRemoval(ComPort port) : base(port) { }
    public override string ToString() => $"{Port} was removed.";
}
```

Utility classes are:

```
public abstract class Enumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public abstract IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() =>
        GetEnumerator();
}
```

And:

```
public abstract class ValueObject<T> : IEquatable<ValueObject<T>>
            where T : ValueObject<T>
{
    protected abstract IEnumerable<object> EqualityCheckAttributes { get; }

    public override int GetHashCode() =>
        EqualityCheckAttributes
            .Aggregate(0, (hash, a) => hash = hash * 31 + (a?.GetHashCode() ?? 0));

    public override bool Equals(object obj) =>
        Equals(obj as ValueObject<T>);

    public virtual bool Equals(ValueObject<T> other) =>
        other != null &&
        GetType() == other.GetType() &&
        EqualityCheckAttributes.SequenceEqual(other.EqualityCheckAttributes);

    public static bool operator ==(ValueObject<T> left, ValueObject<T> right) =>
        Equals(left, right);

    public static bool operator !=(ValueObject<T> left, ValueObject<T> right) =>
        !Equals(left, right);
}
```

Comment: `ComPortList` not implementing `IList` - hadn't expected this from you who recommended me the book on framwork design :-P It should be an `ObservableComPortCollection` or at least `ComPortCollection`. Also why does it have the `List<ComPort> Items { get; }` property if it's already a list? Are you sure this is your code? ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t the last snippet is his signature in my opinion :P

Comment: @t3chb0t 1) `ComPortList` sounds more natural - one would not say Collection about COM ports. From that book:  "For
example, a type used in mainline scenarios to submit print jobs to print
queues should be named Printer, rather than PrintQueue. Even though
technically the type represents a print queue and not the physical device
(printer), from the scenario point of view, Printer is the ideal name because
most people are interested in submitting print jobs and not in other operations
related to the physical printer device (e.g., configuring the printer)." 2) ReadOnlyCollection<T>.Items?

Answer (score 2):

PnPWatcher.Context is never used

In ComPortList:

> ```
>     void Sync()
>     {
>         lock (Items)
>         {
>             var items = ComPort.Detect();
>
>             foreach (var port in Items.Except(items).ToArray())
>             {                    
>                 Items.Remove(port);
>                 Subject.OnNext(new ComPortRemoval(port));
>             }
>
>             foreach (var port in items.Except(Items).ToArray())
>             {
>                 Items.Add(port);
>                 Subject.OnNext(new ComPortAddition(port));
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

You are enumerating the list plenty of times with those .ToArray() 
If update the list of items after rising events you safe a lot of resources and is more comprensible

```
    void Sync()
    {
        lock (Items)
        {
            var currentItems = ComPort.Detect();

            foreach (var port in Items.Except(currentItems))
            {                    
                Subject.OnNext(new ComPortRemoval(port));
            }

            foreach (var port in currentItems.Except(Items))
            {
                Subject.OnNext(new ComPortAddition(port));
            }

            Items.Clear();
            Items.AddRange(currentItems);
        }
    }
```

ValueObject
What is the purpose of this class ?

> ```
>     public override int GetHashCode() =>
>         EqualityCheckAttributes
>             .Aggregate(0, (hash, a) => hash = hash * 31 + (a?.GetHashCode() ?? 0));
> ```

In this form "hash =" is useless and you are also risking an overflow exception

```
    public override int GetHashCode() =>
        EqualityCheckAttributes
            .Aggregate(0, (hash, a) =>
            {
                unchecked
                {
                    return hash * 31 + (a?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
                }
            });
```

Enumerable:

> ```
> public abstract class Enumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
> {
>     public abstract IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
>     IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() =>
>         GetEnumerator();
> }
> ```

This class doesn't have any purpose, you can move the only not abstract method in the only class that inherits Enumerable (and remove confusion with System.Enumerable)

PS: If you want to simplify the interaction with WMI i wrote a wrapper around it:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsMonitor.Standard/

So to retrieves those ports:

```
var ports = PnPEntity.Retrieve()
                           .Where(x => x.ClassGuid == "{4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}")
                            .ToArray();
```

Comment: In original code subscriber can access `Items` from `OnNext` event handler and get updated enumeration. Your `Sync` implementation breaks this behavior.

Comment: @NikitaB I don't know about `OnNext()` implementation but this code is inside a lock, nothing should be updated before it has been released.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti `OnNext` is Rx's equivalent of event invocation. So it can invoke an arbitrary delegate, including, for example: `comPortList.Subscribe(cpu => comPortList.ToArray())`. This delagete is called from inside the lock whenever `OnNext` is called. `lock` does not prevent reentrency.

Comment: What OP can do is store all changes in single event argument (similar to `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs`) and invoke event only once. Then suggested refactoring will work.

Comment: @NikitaB right! I was that blindly focused on `ToArray()` that I didn't even see the `Remove()`/`Add()` thing. :man_facepalming: